# I need to create a Load more button that loads 4 items it is clicked. After it loads all the items a reset button shows and resets the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The idea is that it only shows 4 items at first, which is working properly. When you press the Load More button it loads 4 more items until it reaches the end. When there is no more content to show the Reset button appears and when clicked it only shows the initial 4 items. All that is working fine. What is happening is that after it resets and it loads all the items again the Reset button does not show up anymore and off course I can't reset the page. I have to refresh the page in order to work properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".content").slice(0, 4).show();
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
    if ($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#resetBtn").show();
      $("#loadMore").addClass("hideLoadMore");
    }
    $("#resetBtn").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".content:visible").slice(4, 30).slideUp();
      $("#loadMore").addClass("showloadMore");
      $(this).addClass("hideResetButton");
      console.log(this);
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.content {

  display: none;
}

.noContent {
  color: #000 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hideLoadMore {
  display: none !important;
}

.showloadMore {
  display: block!important;
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
}
.hideResetButton {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="content col-md-6">
          <div class="single-news mb-4">

            <!-- Grid row -->
            <div class="row">

              <!-- Grid column -->
              <div class="col-md-3">

                <!--Image-->
                <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1 mb-4">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="images/GwenBelton.jpg"" alt=" Sample image">
                  <a>
                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                  </a>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- Grid column -->

              <!-- Grid column -->
              <div class="col-md-9">

                <!-- Excerpt -->
                <p class="font-weight-bold dark-grey-text">Gwendolyn Belton</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <div class="col-11 text-truncate pl-0 mb-3">
                    <a href="#!" class="dark-grey-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
                  </div>
                  <a><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- Grid column -->

            </div>
            <!-- Grid row -->

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content col-md-6">
          <div class="single-news mb-4">

            <!-- Grid row -->
            <div class="row">

              <!-- Grid column -->
              <div class="col-md-3">

                <!--Image-->
                <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1 mb-4">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="images/GwenBelton.jpg"" alt=" Sample image">
                  <a>
                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                  </a>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- Grid column -->

              <!-- Grid column -->
              <div class="col-md-9">

                <!-- Excerpt -->
                <p class="font-weight-bold dark-grey-text">Gwendolyn Belton</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <div class="col-11 text-truncate pl-0 mb-3">
                    <a href="#!" class="dark-grey-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
                  </div>
                  <a><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- Grid column -->

            </div>
            <!-- Grid row -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<div id="loadMore" class=" d-flex justify-content-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load
      More</button></div>

  <div id="resetBtn" class=" d-flex justify-content-center" style="display: none!important;"><button type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button></div>
```

Comment: @Taplar I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, there are a few issues:

1. The bootstrap class `d-flex` effectively applies `display: flex`.
2. The event listener for `#resetBtn` is added inside the event listener for `#loadMore`, so a new event listener is added to `#resetBtn` every time `#loadMore` is clicked.

Steps to the solution:

1 - Stop using `style="display:`... Instead use bootstrap classes `d-none` and `d-flex`.

```
<div id="resetBtn" class=" d-flex justify-content-center" style="display: none!important;">
```

Becomes

```
<div id="resetBtn" class="d-none justify-content-center">
```

2 - Move `#resetBtn` event listener outside of `#loadMore` event listener.

```
$("#loadMore").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
  if ($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
    $("#resetBtn").show();
    $("#loadMore").addClass("hideLoadMore");
  }
  $("#resetBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content:visible").slice(4, 30).slideUp();
    $("#loadMore").addClass("showloadMore");
    $(this).addClass("hideResetButton");
    console.log(this);
  });
})
```

Becomes

```
$("#loadMore").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
  if ($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
    $("#resetBtn").show();
    $("#loadMore").addClass("hideLoadMore");
  }
})
$("#resetBtn").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content:visible").slice(4, 30).slideUp();
  $("#loadMore").addClass("showloadMore");
  $(this).addClass("hideResetButton");
  console.log(this);
});
```

3 - Use `toggleClass` to remove `d-flex` and apply `d-none` and vice versa.

```
$("#resetBtn").show();
$("#loadMore").addClass("hideLoadMore");
```

Becomes

```
// shows reset button because it is hidden at this point
$("#resetBtn").toggleClass('d-none d-flex');
// hides load more button because it is shown at this point
$("#loadMore").toggleClass('d-none d-flex');
```

And

```
$("#loadMore").addClass("showloadMore");
$(this).addClass("hideResetButton");
```

Becomes

```
// shows load more button because it's hidden at this point
$("#loadMore").toggleClass('d-none d-flex');
// hides reset button because it is shown at this point
$(this).toggleClass('d-none d-flex');
```